# Memory leak only in release mode with Proguard

Tags: android, android-proguard

I have an Android App that works well in debug mode, but that has some kind of memory leak in release mode. Basically, it is really slow and the following line appears repeatedly in logcat:

```
dalvikvm  D  WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 91ms
```

If I don't obfuscate, don't shrink and don't optimize in proguard, then the release works. If I do one of them, I have this error. I use the following lines:

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
```

I am using multiple external libraries that use some native (i.e. JNI) code, and I have no idea what could be wrong.

- How can I identify where the issue comes from?
- Can I tell proguard to optimize/shrink/obfuscate only one package, so that I can try to isolate the problem?

Comment: That's not necessarily a memory leak though, maybe you are just using large data.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell Proguard to not interfere with, I mean obfuscate, packages and subpackages using instructions like this in the proguard config file:

```
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class okio.** { *; }
```

You can also tell it to keep classes annotated with a specific annotation using:

```
-keep class com.your.annotation
-keep @com.your.annotation class * { *; }
```

The first keep instruction makes sure it doesn't remove the annotation itself, and the second keeps anything annotated with it.

The full Proguard manual with other examples can be found [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html).

Comment: What about telling it to not shrink and not optimize packages and annotations? Does "keep" do that?

Comment: @JonesV You'd have to check the documentation for that. There are a few different -keepxyz instructions and one of them will probably cover optimising or shrinking.